# Upgrade PHP 5.1.x to 5.3.x with XAMPP for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, upgrade, php, xampp

Using Windows XP SP3. I installed the xampp to d:\xampp.
I started it and everything worked fine (at least the indications were good).
I want to use MediaWiki and it says that it can't work with PHP5.1 which is the version installed by XAMPP.

I followed the instructions I found in [this](http://www.retireat21.com/forums/design-development/1512-upgrading-php-version-xampp.html) thread, but now the Apache service does not start.
The control panel for XAMPP says that the Apache service started though it does not show an indication of `running`.

I am not familiar with the XAMPP at all. I don't know where to look for the error.

**Question:** How do I upgrade to PHP 5.3

---

I Must have gone blind or something...
Reinstalling XAMPP revealed that the version of the PHP is 5.3.1 as suggested by [itadok](https://superuser.com/questions/110013/upgrade-php-5-1-x-to-5-3-x-with-xampp-for-windows/110022#110022)'s answer

My mistake was that I checked the phpmyadmin for the version and it stated server version and not PHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [release notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.7.3/xampp-win32-1.7.3.txt/view), it seems that the latest XAMPP comes with PHP 5.3.1. So I suggest you just download the latest XAMPP version.

Comment: bummer. I must have downloaded an old version... I'll try that and get back.

Comment: Looking at it, I installed XAMPP version 1.7.3 (supposed to have PHP 5.3), but in phpmyadmin it showed a status of an old PHP version. I am reinstalling to see where I messed up.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend downloading the bitnami stack for Mediawiki [here](http://bitnami.org/stack/mediawiki).  This will save you more hassle installing mediawiki itself.

Comment: Looks good. I already resolved my problem so I won't use this for now, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just install a newer version of xampp?
I do not know where you using xampp for. I it is just for one project, you probably can just install a newer version. 
And in your XAMPP window is there a option to click on called Setup? Maybe you can relocate your xampp folder.

Let me now.